# Label and symbol with condition in layer properties under style tab

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, labeling

I have forest areas. I want to put tree.svg with condition.

```
Layer properties-> style-> background -> shape ->svg
```

Something like this:

```
if (myfield<1300 , then show, C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./svg/gpsicons/tree.svg

if (myfield>1300 and <2000 , then show,C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./svg/symbol/landuse_coniferous_and_deciduous.svg

if (myfield>2000 and <3000 , then C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./svg/symbol/landuse_coniferous.svg
```

I don't know to make code under expression string builder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer by @iant is the best method to use (when you get it working, you should accept his answer).

Just want to add that you can use the following expressions in your filter for your 3 individual rules (you can add rules by clicking the `+` as shown in the image, set the expression filter and the svg symbol):

```
"myfield" < 1300

"myfield" > 1300 AND "myfield" < 2000

"myfield" > 2000 AND "myfield" < 3000
```

[image: Rule-based style]

Answer (score 5):

I think your best option would be to use `Rule Based` classification - there are a number of tutorials available - I like [this one](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification) from Linfiniti.

Comment: I use rule based option. Thank you both of you, it is that, excellent.